# Custom component upgrade - Missing buttons in com_categories view

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, development, fix-my-code, upgrade

I'm currently adapting a custom extension a former colleague of mine has developed for Joomla 2.5, so that it runs under Joomla 3.4.

The component in question uses com_categories for category management (index.php?option=com_categories&&extension=com_whatever).

When the categories view loads, however, some of the action buttons, namely "New", are now missing.

What shall I update in the component to make com_categories load the full set of action buttons?

Screenshot of the view:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/60zfak311diin9w/Screenshot%202015-06-01%2022.52.22.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your access.xml properly in order to see the buttons. The two required permissions are `core.create` and `core.edit.state`

```
<section name="component">
    <action name="core.admin" title="JACTION_ADMIN" description="JACTION_ADMIN_COMPONENT_DESC" />
    <action name="core.manage" title="JACTION_MANAGE" description="JACTION_MANAGE_COMPONENT_DESC" />
    <action name="core.create" title="JACTION_CREATE" description="JACTION_CREATE_COMPONENT_DESC" />
    <action name="core.delete" title="JACTION_DELETE" description="JACTION_DELETE_COMPONENT_DESC" />
    <action name="core.edit" title="JACTION_EDIT" description="JACTION_EDIT_COMPONENT_DESC" />
    <action name="core.edit.own" title="JACTION_EDITOWN" description="JACTION_EDITOWN_COMPONENT_DESC" />
    <action name="core.edit.state" title="JACTION_EDITSTATE" description="JACTION_EDITSTATE_COMPONENT_DESC" />
</section>
<section name="category">
    <action name="core.create" title="JACTION_CREATE" description="COM_CATEGORIES_ACCESS_CREATE_DESC" />
    <action name="core.delete" title="JACTION_DELETE" description="JACTION_DELETE_COMPONENT_DESC" />
    <action name="core.edit" title="JACTION_EDIT" description="JACTION_EDIT_COMPONENT_DESC" />
    <action name="core.edit.own" title="JACTION_EDITOWN" description="JACTION_EDITOWN_COMPONENT_DESC" />
    <action name="core.edit.state" title="JACTION_EDITSTATE" description="JACTION_EDITSTATE_COMPONENT_DESC" />
</section>
```

You may want to define category level permissions as well here so that you can give granular permissions to your individual categories.

Comment: Actually, you should add an additional section with name "category" for category specific permissions.
I think it gracefully falls back to component permissions if the category section is missing thought.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that why I mention about category section in last line of my answer. but anyway added category section in my answer to avoid any confusion.

Comment: @Nagarjun thanks a lot for the pointers. The thing with this extension is that it has no ACL layer whatsoever and I am at a loss when it comes to committing all the required changes.

Comment: Interestingly, the only other view does show the item creation button (https://www.dropbox.com/s/r50cen0hilpcrkr/Screenshot%202015-06-02%2019.55.32.png?dl=0). How exactly do I tell com_categories to load re buttons in the extension=com_whatever parameter?

Comment: When you add access.xml with above content, the categories page will automatically loads required buttons. No additional code changes required.

Comment: I've created access.xml in /path/to/administrator/components/com_whatever/ and still no buttons show up in the categories view.

Comment: As it turns out, the actual issue was caused by the #__assets table. I0ve manually imported all the prettiest records straight from the original 2.5 environment and voilà, the action buttons are showing up- Thank you for the ACL hints, anyway. Might come in handy down  the road-